# Programming style: Use constants for status codes?

Tags: coding-style, constants

Is it good practise to use constants for status codes, e.g. when returning the result of an AJAX function to the caller? E.G.:

```
CONST STATUS_INVALID_ENTRY = 1;
CONST STATUS_ENTRY_OK = 2;
$.getJSON("addRecord.php", $("#addRecord").serialize(), function (result) {
     switch (result.status) {
     case STATUS_INVALID_ENTRY:
         ...do something
     case STATUS_ENTRY_OK:
         ...do something else
}
```

Or is it preferred to use the slightly worse performing:

```
     switch (result.status) {
     case "INVALID_ENTRY":
         ...do something
     case "ENTRY_OK":
         ...do something else
     }
```

Of course for the first solution the constants would have to be defined equally in "addRecord.php"

Comment: It is, to make the code friendly for its readers.

Comment: It really depends on the language and what you're doing. In dynamic languages like python a status can just be a string, that's perfectly acceptable and expected. In static languages like Java the convention is to use an Enum. In C/C++ you're forced to use enum/int in switch/case. In bash a return status code must be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case it is more appropriate to use constants.
But also make sure it is consistent with other parts of the code/project you're working on for readability.